# How to get the ckeditor.js script to work on a site that uses the Google pagespeed module and Drupal's ckeditor?

Tags: 6

On a Drupal 6 site I installed Google pagespeed module. It's working fine but my `ckeditor.js` script is not working.

I searched Google and found there is known problem with pagespeed and ckeditor.

All sites are saying to add a disallow `ckeditor.js` in the `pagespeed.conf` file. Well I tried but the ckeditor just doesn't work! Here's one url

[drupals website discussing this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1095908)I have the ckeditor module enabled for Drupal 6. The status report says it's ckeditor 3.5.1

Any suggestions to get this to work?

Comment: Hi I couldn't find an appropriate tag I tried

Comment: Please review my edited version (and tag ...). Feel free to furhter correct, or even rollback if you don't like it at all. And edit your question to (a) add a hyperlink to that "Google pagespeed" module and (b) clarify if you're only using the ckeditor SCRIPT, or if you're using the [CK Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) **module** (as per the "Drupal's ckeditor" in the title of your question ...).